# using awk to sort data into a set format

Tags: awk, rpm

I am running

```
rpm -Vqf
```

to check if various system files are correct.
The below is a sample output.

```
S.5....T.  c /etc/enviro
missing     /var/run/abrt
file /etc/bluetooth is not owned by any package
```

I would like the output to be like the below in order to see the full path to the file. If permisions `/ownr/checksum...` are correct, if it is missing or not owned by a package.

```
/etc/enviro|S.5....T.
/var/run/abrt|missing
/etc/bluetooth|not owned
```

I was looking at `awk` but can't quit get it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your output is *always* as presented for the three examples you provided, the following should work:

```
rpm -Vqf <arguments> | awk '/(\/[^/ ]+)+$/ {printf("%s|%s\n",$NF,$1);next} /is not owned/{printf("%s|not owned\n",$2)}'
```

This call to `awk` does the following:

- If a line *ends* with an absolute file path (i.e. a `/` followed by any number of "non-slashes" (that are also no spaces), and that pattern possibly repeated), use `printf` to print the last record (= whitespace-separated string), which is the filepath, followed by the `|`, and then the first record. Then, skip execution to the next input line (otherwise you might get multiple output for the same input line).
- If a line contains the string "is not owned", print the second record (which is the file path *assuming that the output always reads* `file <name> is not owned ...`), followed by the fixed string "not owned".

Comment: Thank you very much however on the file <name is not owned i seem to get package | file not sure why but thank  you so much

Comment: See edited text, there was a typo (missing "space" after `/` in the square brackets) XD